# Please remove the programming tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

The [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag is even more useless than the completely useless [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code) tag. Please delete the [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag so we can clear the system up a bit.

Comment: I agree it really is rather superfluous on Stack Overflow. :) (A bit like the "stackoverflow" tag here on meta - few of those questions are specific to SO but not the other sites.)

Comment: The stackoverflow tag is just as inappropriate on SO.com.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps, now that there's meta. Most of those should probably be moved here.

Comment: Oh, see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg/3013#3013

Comment: @Rich B stackoverflow could also be a programming related tag on stackoverflow.com

Comment: There are still questions tagged "programming". Maybe it needs to be blacklisted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't see any logical reason for that tag to be there. If SO is a programming site, you would assume all questions should be programming related.

Comment: But what if it's a Friday afternoon (somewhere) and you're in the mood for **fun**?

Comment: Those fun questions MUST be programming related!

Comment: But the not-programming-related tag has more questions then the programming tag, how do you explain that? :p

Comment: @DeadHead: I explain it on the grounds that Rich B clearly doesn't know where to find those people posting not-programming-related questions.

Comment: The not-programming-related tag predates the system of flagging questions as off-topic, and misguided though well-meaning noob users like myself of 2 years ago would use it to try to group off-topic questions together.

Answer (score 11):

If the programming tag isn't deleted, every post on StackOverflow should have the programming tag.

Answer (score 4):

Just to set expectation: at the moment we have "merge" and "rename"... so AFAIK we can't do this without more input from the team.

Comment: DELETE FROM Tags WHERE TagName="programming"?

Comment: Otherwise I will just do it myself. Just figured this was a good case where the tag definitely did not need to exist and could be taken out automagically.

Comment: Jeff or one of the other core team members might be able to do it in SQL or equivalent.  Community moderators do not have that ability. :(

Comment: @Bill: Jeez, what good are you people anyway?

Comment: @Rich: I have a cousin who can save you up to 15% on auto insurance. ;p

Comment: @Bill: Was it that delicious gecko? Because if it was, we have an issue...

Answer (score -2):

Well, just deleting the tags won't work, since anyone with enough rep can just remake the tag... you'd also have to block the tags, which just doesn't make sense...

Comment: Deleting them will be fine. We can manage it from there.